# Передача многомерного массива через AJAX на сервер

Tags: json, php, javascript

Как передать многомерный массив через AJAX на сервер ? Мне надо на сервере JSON превратить в объект

```
var dataCat = {
        color: "black", 
        eat: "yes"
    }
  var genObj = {
    cat :  JSON.stringify(dataCat)
};
  var xhr = getXMLRequestObj('POST', url, serialize(genObj))  // 3 аргумент это    xhr.send
```

Результат print_r($_POST) выдаст.

```
   Array
(
     [cat] => {\"color\":\"black\",\"eat\":\"yes\"}
)
```

Если не многомерный

```
var genObj = {
    cat :  'Marusia'
};
```

то серверный print_r($_POST) выдаст.

```
 Array
(  
[cat] => Marusia
)

 function serialize(a) {
 var s = [];
  if ( a.constructor == Array ) {
   for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
       s.push( a[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent( a[i].value ) );
} else {
   for ( var j in a )
       s.push( j + "=" + encodeURIComponent( a[j] ) );
}
 return s.join("&");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array
(
     [cat] => {\"color\":\"black\",\"eat\":\"yes\"}
)
```

Если так, тогда:

```
$data = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    $data[$key] = ($json = @json_decode($value)) 
       ? $json
       : $value;
```

Ваши данные будут в **$data**

Answer (score 0):

Ну а в php `json_decode($_POST)` не пробовали?
У меня эта функция прекрасно декодирует строку JSON в многомерный массив

Comment: пишет "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given i.."

Comment: может сервер пустой ответ отдает?